# How to return all words that begin and end in certain characters?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Sorry.. I have asked a very similar question earlier.. However this time i want to retrieve all words that end in certain characters

I have a list of words as follows

```
        List<string> words = new List<string>();
        words.Add("abet");
        words.Add("abbots"); //<---Return this
        words.Add("abrupt");
        words.Add("abduct");
        words.Add("abnats"); //<--return this.
        words.Add("acmatic");


        //Now return all words of 6 letters that begin with letter "a" and has "ts" as the 5th and 6th letter   
        //the result should return the words "abbots" and "abnats"
        var result = from w in words
                     where w.Length == 6 && w.StartsWith("a") && //????
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't compiled and tested this, but it should work.

```
var result = from w in words
                     where w.Length == 6 && w.StartsWith("a") && w.EndsWith("ts")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `EndsWith` to check for characters at the end.

```
var result = from w in words
                     where w.Length == 6 && w.StartsWith("a") && w.EndsWith("ts")
```

Use `IndexOf` to check for words starting at ***certain position*** (in your case starting at 5th):

```
  var result = from w in words
                     where w.Length == 6 && w.StartsWith("a") && (w.Length > 5 && w.IndexOf("ts", 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use .EndsWith() for suffixes.

```
var results = from w in words where w.Length == 6 
    && w.StartsWith("a") 
    && w.EndsWith("ts");
```

Answer (score 0):

You be able to use the `EndsWith()` function:

**Usage:**

```
var test=   FROM w in words
           WHERE w.Length == 6
              && w.StartsWith("a")
              && w.EndsWith("ts");
```

**Alterative:**

```
var test = words.Where(w =>w.Length==6 && w.StartsWith("a") && w.EndsWith("ts"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A Regex is your friend here:

```
Regex regEx = new Regex("^a[A-Za-z]*ts$");
var results = from w in words where regEx.Match(w).Success select w;
```

Also note than when using LINQ's query comprehension syntax, you'll need a `select` at the end of it (even if it's just the original `from` variable.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a bit of regex if you feel up to it:

```
string pattern = @"^(a[a-zA-Z]*a)$";
var result = from w in words
where w.Length == 6 && System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(w, pattern) select w;
```

This should match anything starting with 'a' and ending with 'a'.